# Open File With Associated Application

Tags: c#

i want to know how one can open pdf files or text files using their default programs,let say i want to open a pdf file and my default program is adobe reader,i know i can use this code below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:/MYSQL.pdf");
        }
```

but i want to create a program for example,a program called `bb.exe`
if i have a directory called drop and inside it, i have sub directories `viewer and files` but the `bb.exe` is not in any subdirectory its just in the main directory drop,the viewer directory has `adobe reader.exe` and the files directory has pdf files.

when i click bb.exe which is inside the drop directory it should open the pdf file in the files folder and it should use the `adobe reader.exe` in the viewer folder....how can this be done??what materials should i read?? i need ideas on how this can be done or if anyone can explain i will greatly appreciate thanks in advance

Comment: Please rephrase your question more clearly.

Comment: Adobe Reader requires installation, so it's difficult to see how you're going to be able to use your own version of it in your own folder.

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to do something like this?

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"notepad", "XMLFile1.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: something like that let me try